# iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

I'm trying reading a .xls file. I have a French character **Crèche**.
I'm getting the PHPExcel error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
> Message:  iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string
> Filename: Shared/String.php

My code to read the excel:

```
include(APPPATH."/third_party/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");      
$tmpfname = "$targetFile"; // file path   
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);  
$excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
$worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
```

Any suggestion please!

Comment: I think you need to set character encoding to `UTF-8` while reading excel file from phpexcel. Referring this link may help - http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/class-PHPExcel_Reader_CSV.html

Comment: I tryed but same resut.$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
            $excelReader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');

Comment: Did anyone find solution of this? i am also facing same issue.